# public/.htaccess file not found

Tags: typescript, .htaccess, configuration, public, configure

I'm building a music streaming platform but trying to install the script it was like. I saw this error text that says

> Make sure public/.htaccess file has been uploaded properly to your server and is writable.

how to fix this error? I don't know what else to add to my .htaccess file

My code are

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js .xml

DefaultLanguage en-US

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

https://music.mair.name.ng *Mair Musix*
```

Details are shown in the image below

The script installation

[image]

[image]

I don't know how to configure the **public/htaccess**

Comment: `https://music.mair.name.ng *Mair Musix*` - that is absolutely _not_ a valid line inside a .htaccess. If you meant this to be a comment, then you need to start the line with a `#`.

Comment: Why would you want to _add_ anything to that configuration file? That error you post ("Make sure public/.htaccess file has been uploaded properly to your server and is writable.") says that the file is not writable, as it is expected.

Comment: Please how to adjust that?